# Anchor Tag with Prevented Default Behavior Not Executing Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, haml

I'm encountering a peculiar issue within Haml views where a clickable image is configured within an anchor tag. The desired behavior is to execute an Ajax call when the image "Button" is clicked. However, despite various attempts, including using javascript:void(0) and href='', to prevent the anchor tag's default behavior, the Ajax call doesn't execute as expected (which means the #generic-button.button event was not called). It's worth noting that using href='' results in an unwanted page reload, and using href='#' also does not help.

When we first land on the form, the click on the button does not invoke the event (I've verified through console logs), but if I reload the page the button click works and whatever's inside the event function happens as it should.

**Expected Behaviour:**

Upon clicking the clickable image when first landing on the page, the Ajax call should execute, I'm using Ajax call as an example here, It could be any thing inside the event function.

**Note:**
In my case I've verified the Ajax call is working as expected but the clickable image's behaviour is the problem here. Another thing to note here is that reloading the url makes the Ajax call/clickable image work.

**here's what I have setup:**

```
%a#generic-button.button{'data-generic-id' => generic-id, :href => 'javascript:void(0);'}
  = image_tag('https://www.example.com/test/generic-button.svg', id: 'Generic Image')
```

**and the Ajax call:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#generic-button.button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var genericId = $(this).data('generic-id');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/generic-action',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
    data: { generic_id: genericId },
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        // Handle success logic here
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      // Handle error logic here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What about walking this back to basic troubleshooting - can you take out the ajax call functionality and just try and do `event.preventDefault();` and a `console.log()` without it reloading the page? My first suspicion is that the button is a type of `submit`, which will cause the form to submit and reload the page, irrespective of what you do it, because of the order of execution.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't show any response upon the initial page load. It starts working as expected only after I reload the page.

Comment: Does clicking the button without any ajax call still reload the page?

Comment: The problem is that the button click doesn't work when the page first loads not the reload. The note about it working after a page reload was added for context.

Comment: Is this function wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(() => .... )`?

Comment: yes. It appears that the JavaScript is not loading when the template initially renders. Even a simple console log in the JavaScript section doesn't work. Strangely, the JavaScript becomes functional after a page reload.

Comment: I'd start there then and figure out why .js isn't starting on page load. Once you figure that out, it'll probably solve your problem here, too.